# Origin Destination Variables Stata

Tags: stata, panel

I am working on a panel data with observations for all the US states for years 2000-2018. My goal is to analyze migration flows across all the states. I need to create Origin-Destination pairs for my variables, in order to analyze the flows. Right now I only have the origin variable, like in the example below:

Example:

```
StateID_Orig. 

AL             
AL             
AL             
AL
```

and need to create the destination variable, in order to make it look like in the example below.

Example:

```
StateID_Orig.   StateID_Dest

AL              AK
AL              AR
AL              AZ
AL              CA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the destination data not in the same dataset? This kind of merger is very fragile.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your answer and apologies for not being clear enough. 
What I am trying to do is create pairs of data in Column StateID_Dest based on duplicate values in Column StateID_Orig. The variable StateID_Dest does not exist in a differ dataset and I am not trying to merge. I am trying to create a new variable (StateID_Dest), using repeated values from StateID_Orig and create pairs.

Comment: You are trying to merge with information from elsewhere in the dataset. That's my point.  It is an exercise in finding the right subscripts to copy across.

Answer (score 0):

```
input str2 var1
AL
AK
AZ
CA
end

tempfile DATA
save `DATA'

rename var1 var2

cross using `DATA'

rename var2 origin
rename var1 dest

sort origin dest

list, sepby(origin)

     +---------------+
     | origin   dest |
     |---------------|
  1. |     AK     AK |
  2. |     AK     AL |
  3. |     AK     AZ |
  4. |     AK     CA |
     |---------------|
  5. |     AL     AK |
  6. |     AL     AL |
  7. |     AL     AZ |
  8. |     AL     CA |
     |---------------|
  9. |     AZ     AK |
 10. |     AZ     AL |
 11. |     AZ     AZ |
 12. |     AZ     CA |
     |---------------|
 13. |     CA     AK |
 14. |     CA     AL |
 15. |     CA     AZ |
 16. |     CA     CA |
     +---------------+
```

Comment: I referred to this post in writing this answer: https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-12/msg00698.html